# Typescript React cant find property inside object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Sorry for the confusing title but I didnt know how to title it better.

I am fetching some data from a food api and storing it into a state.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<null | {}>(null);
```

The above stateful variable is initialized as null and then **later changes to being an object when the fetching is finished `setData(apiData)` that has one property called meals which is an array of objects**

I am trying to pass the fetched data to a component called Card but i get this **error:
" Property 'meals' does not exsist on type '{}'  "**

```
  data !== null && <Card data={data?.meals} />
```

I thought that It probably cant recognize the property 'meals' on the object because the data is not done fetching when it tries to access it so i decide to check if the data is not equal to null but that is not working either...

Any idea towards what I am doing wrong ? I am new to Typescript.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `{}` means "an object with no properties". Thus, you're saying that it will not have a `meals` property, nor any other. You need to provide a type that matches what the data will look like. I don't know exactly what that type will look like, so you will need to fill in what it's properties are, but an example with some properties i made up is:

```
interface Meal {
  mealId: string;
  calories: number;
}

interface Data {
  id: string;
  meals: Meal[];
}

// ... used like:
const [data, setData] = useState<null | Data>(null);

// ... and:
data !== null && <Card data={data.meals} />
```

Comment: hmm makes sense now that i am thinking of it. I was not sure how to write it. I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you for your answer